# Azure Data Factory - REST to Azure SQL with filter

Tags: json, api, rest, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

What is the best approach to perform the following task within the Azure Data Factory:

1. Call Rest-API and get json as a response
2. Parse json and copy some of the values to one Azure SQL-table (according to some filter) and the other values to another SQL-table.

I guess, it is not possible to perform this in one step by using the copy-activity.
So a kind of staging-step might be needed.
What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

1.create a copy activity,source：REST sink:blob,copy REST response to blob storage json file.

2.create a dataflow,source: json file in blob storage

then create a `conditional split`, according to filter to different sink.

Hope this can help you.